# correct update of bayesian posteriors

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

the question looks a bit artificial but I simply tried to get rid of useless details.

There are two persons, A, and B. they each got a number, *i* and *b*, correspondingly. and their task is to guess the right number *c=(a+b)/2.*
Each of them  knows his/her own number but not the number of the other.

If the B's prior beliefs were distributed normally (or by any distribution that is know to us and to B), how B should update his posterior probabilities if 
we informed B that a < K (a certain number).

In other words, we just tell B, that *c<(K+b)/2* .

I guess he should 'cut' the tail of his distribution right to *K*, and then redistribute the probabilities to the left of the *K*. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using Greek letters for unknown quantities and Roman letters for known quantities. So the problem you have is that you want a probability distribution for 
$$ \gamma = \frac{\alpha+b}{2} = \frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{b}{2} $$
where 
$$ \alpha \sim N(m,s^2)\mathrm{I}(\alpha<K)$$ 
which is shorthand for the probability density function (pdf)
$$ p(\alpha) = \frac{\frac{1}{s}\phi\left(\frac{\alpha-m}{s}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{K-m}{s}\right)}\mathrm{I}(\alpha<K)$$
where $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are the pdf and cumulative distribution function for a standard normal random variable. The term in the denominator is exactly the area under the pdf to the right of $K$ if $\alpha \sim N(m,s^2)$ which is necessarily less than 1. So, as you point out, the probability is redistributed to the left of $K$.

By Theorem 3.5.6 in Casella and Berger, the probability density function for $\gamma$ is 
$$ p(\gamma) = 
\frac{\frac{2}{s}\phi\left(\frac{(2\gamma-b)-m}{s}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{K-m}{s}\right)}\mathrm{I}((2\gamma-b)<K) = 
\frac{\frac{2}{s}\phi\left(\frac{(2\gamma-b)-m}{s}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{K-m}{s}\right)}\mathrm{I}\left(\gamma<\frac{K+b}{2}\right).
$$
Thus, you can see that $\gamma$ is truncated to be less than $(K+b)/2$, just as you suspected.

Althought you could work with this density directly, it may be easier to just work with the distribution for $\alpha$ and the equation for $\gamma$, e.g.

1. Sample $\alpha \sim N(m,s^2)$ until $\alpha<K$.
2. Calculate $\gamma = (\alpha+b)/2$.

If you do this many times, you can plot a histogram of the values which is an approximation to the true pdf. You can take an average of the values which will give you an approximation to the expected value for $\gamma$.